# Function inside array of objects not processed and return as string JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects, at this moment there is just one object inside. In this object i have a function that elaborate some properties of the same object. I print, with a loop, the components, but the function is not processed and the string is returned. How can i have the result?

```
let arrMaterie = [
    {
        name: "...",
        a: 4,
        b: 75,
        functionTest: function test() {
            return this.a+this.b;
        }
    }
];

for (let i in arrMaterie) {
    for (let j in arrMaterie[i]) {
        test.innerHTML += arrMaterie[i][j];
    }
}
```

OUTPUT ...475function test() { return this.a - this.b }
and not ...-4-75-**79**

Comment: please show how you're calling the function

Comment: I don't see the function being called anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to detrmine whether the property is a function, and if so call it with `()` - so something like:

```js
let arrMaterie = [
    {
        name: "...",
        a: 4,
        b: 75,
        functionTest: function test() {
            return this.a+this.b;
        }
    }
];

const test = document.getElementById("test");
for (let i in arrMaterie) {
    for (let j in arrMaterie[i]) {
        if(typeof arrMaterie[i][j] == "function"){
          test.innerHTML += arrMaterie[i][j]();
        }
        else{
          test.innerHTML += arrMaterie[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```